# Android Firebase Multiplayer Matchmaking

Tags: android, firebase

I have written a Tic-Tac-Toe app and have also learned a good amount of Firebase in the last 2 weeks. However, I am thinking of adding Multiplayer Matchmaking and real-time turn-by-turn TicTacToe online using Firebase.

So here is what I am thinking:

1. There's a play button.
2. Click on it.
3. It will show a "*Searching for opponents*" TextView.

So I think I should do something to show it open state and then see another player that clicks and shows that open -- Two open then connect them. But what if there are more players? What if 5-6 players click at once when there's no one and it thinks it is empty?

I want that 2 players can be matched out of any number of players. As I am relatively intermediate in Firebase, can anyone help me a bit with the logic and also pretty good if with the workflow and a code snippet.

Thanks in advance,
Android Programmer :)

Comment: This isn't quite a Firebase problem. How would you do the same thing with a normal list of User objects. Start with that

Comment: could you plz elaborate a bit plz sir :)

Comment: *I want that 2 players can be matched out of any number of players* -- Then build said `List<Player>` randomly pick out two objects.

Comment: alright...will try that...thanx for help...maybe useful later on ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can make 2 List

1. available Games
2. players available to join.

Then pick them up on First Come First Serve basis. Assign first player to first available game. Then Change the status of a player to busy (remove it from list) & also change the status of Game to ready (remove it from list)